# Modular MediaWiki

Tags: module, mediawiki, wiki

I wonder if it is possible to configure MediaWiki (or other wiki tools) as a modular predefined wiki. For instance, on a regular wiki page one can freely edit sections, text, everything.

I am looking for a solution that predefines a number of sections (or modules) that can be added to each wiki page. Then users are free to edit inside those sections within their predefined formats.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As for MediaWiki, there is at least one extension that can work that way: [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms), usually used together with Semantic MediaWiki (though that is not necessary). With SF, you will define one or more templates that receives the data entered in the form, and the form can be divided into sections.

A more lighweight solution might be using one of the many [boiler plate extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User%3aRouslanZenetl/Extension%3aBoilerplate#See_Also) available.

Either way, with a wiki you can never force your users to follow a certain scheme. The whole philosophy, making wiki's unique among collaborative tools, is that the users, not you, create not only the content but also the structure for the content!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at your suggestions. It already looks like the boiler plate extension is what I am looking for.

Comment: BTW, yes you're right that wikis in general should be open and free for users to edit and change. But just to provide a background on my questions, the wiki I'm working on is complex in terms of which sections/content should be in each article. Thus a template/framework is needed to simply guide the community. The users are then free to edit and change inside the sections.

Answer (score 0):

The former Semantic Forms is now called Page_Forms and it is not dependent on SMW https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms and can also make use of the Cargo extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo

I would disagree that wiki users cannot or should not be forced to follow a scheme for some types of information, though the default is that they do control the categories and namespaces and can create those at will as the data evolves.  All this means though is that you manage such issues socially rather than with complex permissions structures, i.e. someone undoes your change and says "do it this way instead".  So it's a different kind of forcing, but, still, someone has to make sure categories don't proliferate with bad names, capitalization, etc.

The typical use of forms data is when it must be used to satisfy some legal or professional requirement (say logging for what reason a change was made for Sarbanes-Oxley, or logging what precedents were consulted for logging legal time), or will be providing input strictly to some application (like maps).  It would not be a good idea to rigorize literally every page of a wiki this way.